# For comprehension in slick returns an empty result when a generator return empty (joins)

Tags: scala, slick

Sorry if it's a super noob question, but basically I've this code:

```
  def testGroup(uid : String) = {
    for{
      group <- groups if group.gid === uid
      subtopic <- subtopics if subtopic.stgroupid === uid
    } yield (group,subtopic)
  }
```

If my query can't find any subtopic where it's stgroupid be the same as uid, then the query returns an empty vector, I wish than it returns the group and a null for sutopic or even better, an option type None.

I'm reading Joining and Zipping [1](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0/queries.html#joining-and-zipping) and seems than I need use a left join, for this query is not a big deal but I've other queries where use leftJoin could be not so clear, like:

```
def getGroup(uid: String) = {

for {
  group <- groups if group.gid === uid
  groupToRelated <- relatedgroups if groupToRelated.rgid === group.gid //must use a foreign key here
  related <- groups if groupToRelated.rgrelatedid === related.gid
  subtopic <- subtopics if subtopic.stgroupid === uid
  article <- articles if article.asuttopicid === subtopic.stid
} yield (group, subtopic, article)


}
```

Here, related,subtopic,article could return an empty result, I wish can handle it and if for instance, the query doesnt return sutopic I can  return only the group name then...

thanks!!

Comment: I could not get your question. You are right in saying that you have to use left join. You can make it clearer by using the left join DSL provided by slick.

Comment: Hi mohit, for the first example was simple use join but I'm not sure about the second example: it's several generators and it's not totally clear for me how write this query...can you provide me some example??...

Comment: This will indeed require you to dig into left joins vs. inner joins and play with it until you are comfortable enough to express what you need. Left joins are tricky right now with Slick. Version 3.0 in a few weeks solves that,